# Laravel 8 Routing Subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain

I'm new to using Laravel 8. In previous Laravel version 7, we can pass **subdomain** name with this way

```
    Route::group( [ 'domain' => '{admin}.example.com' ], function () {
        Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index($account)' );
    }
```

But, in Laravel 8 structure code to call **Controller** was changed like this.

```
    Route::domain('{admin}.example.com')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    });
```

I've been looking for the docs but have not found them. Can you show me docs or helping me to send / passing *subdomain* from **web.php** to **Controller**

Comment: What is your error or problem ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti i don't know to pass my subdomain name to my controller using laravel 8. in previous version we can do it using @index($admin)

Comment: I'm not sure that in previous versions `index($account)` was even necessary to pass the parameter to the controller. Using `HomeController@index` and having the parameter in the controller method has always worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply add a parameter to your controller method with the same name as the route parameter. Laravel takes care of binding the variable behind the scenes.

It's not explicitly shown in the docs with reference to controllers, but there is a basic example.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing

Below is an example with a controller.

```php
Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

```php
class HomeController 
{
    public function index($subdomain)
    {
        dd($subdomain);
    }
}
```

://admin.example.com/home

```php
"admin"
```